# Why does this return wrong max?

Tags: python, return, tuples

I need to write a program that returns the max valued stock along with its value. However, It keeps returning `ccc,300` as max valued stock

```py
stock = [('aaa',100),('bbb',12000),('ccc',300)]
def pricechk(stock):
    for name,price in stock:
        var_price =0
        var_name =''
        if price > var_price:
            var_price =price
            var_name =name
        else:
            pass
    return (var_name,var_price)
    
print(pricechk(stock))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code resets the `var_price` and `var_name` variables in each iteration of the `for` loop. Thus, you are simply returning the last stock, because you forget the results from the previous iterations.

The trivial fix is to move

```
    var_price =0
    var_name =''
```

up to before the `for` loop; but of course, Python has a built-in `max` function which you should definitely learn to use.

```py
print(max(stock, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Here, we say that we want the `max` element from the list `stock`, using a simple `lambda` to extract the value to compare from each element.

As an aside, you should probably define how to handle a tie - return both max values? Or pick the one whose name is alphabetically first? The latter of these could be done entirely without a `lambda` if you are willing to switch the order of the elements within each tuple, but is probably less useful for most real-life cases (you want to know that there is a tie, i.e. probably have the code return all `max` elements).

Also, `else: pass` is completely unnecessary. The `else:` clause is optional, so if you don't have an `else:` case, just leave it out.